# creating 2 unique 3 column layouts using HTML/CSS columns

Tags: html, css, footer, multiple-columns

Coding a web page and ran into trouble with a combination of the HTML and CSS. I want to create the same existing 3 column layout I have now in the footer. When I copy/paste and rename the HTML/CSS into the footer, the code does not function as columns. How can I add a second 3 column layout to the footer that will function the same way my first 3 column layout does?

here is the problem html/CSS

```
<div id="columns">

<div class="left column">
    <p>left column</p>
</div>

<div class="middle column">
    <p>middle column.</p>
</div>    

<div class="right column">
   <p>right column.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <!-- 3 column layout would be placed inside the footer -->
```

```
 #columns {
width: 960px;
padding-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}


#columns .column {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 1%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}

#columns .left {
    float: left;
}

#columns .middle {
    float: left;
}
#columns .right {
    float: right;
    #container #col1 {
    width: 320px;
    float: left;

 }
```

Comment: The CSS specifies `#columns`, so none of those styles will apply if the classes are put in the footer. Change the CSS to just specify the classes, not the ID.

Comment: Also, your question should contain the HTML/CSS that _doesn't_ work. How can we tell what you did wrong when you just write "would be placed here"?

Comment: is this what you mean?
<div class="footer">
<div class="left footer">
        <p>left column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="middle footer">
        <p>middle column.</p>
    </div>    
    <div class="right footer">
       <p>right column.</p>
   </div>
</div> #footer {
width: 960px;
padding-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 0px;}
#footer .column {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 1%;
    border: solid 1px #000;}
#footer .left {
    float: left;}
#footer .middle {
    float: left;}
#footer .right {
    float: right;
    #container #col1 {
    width: 320px;
    float: left;}

Comment: I have no idea if that's what I mean, since it's totally unreadable. Edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I floated everything left and made sure the footer and columns had enough width to sit next to each other and it appears to do what you want it to:

```
#columns {
padding-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
width:1200px;
}
.column {
position: relative;
width: 300px;
padding: 1%;
border: solid 1px #000;
}
.column{float:left;}
.footer{width:1200px;}
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/trG5B/